# Load a Style Only for Specific OS Version

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
               ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

By default it will be applied to all buttons in all OSes but I only want to apply it if the user is using Windows 8.

Is there any way to activate the style from code-behind after checking the `Environment.OSVersion.Version` property? Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your bootstrapper code(that what get's executed before XAML is shown) and create simple switch that will pick correct XAML file based on OS version.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/OS7.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
XamlReader reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
var dic = (ResourceDictionary)reader.LoadAsync(info.Stream);

//then locate ResourceDictionary throgh Application.Current.Resources
yourDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
```

You can also create simple trigger that binds to static OS version property and switches Button's template, but it's rather limiting because you can swap only template. It might help you;

```
   <Window.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="OS7" TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="blue" BorderBrush="blue">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>


        <!-- DEFALT -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="red" BorderBrush="blue">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Just an example. Replace IsMouseOver with DataTrigger and STATIC binding against OS version-->
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OS7}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think style is theme based and cannot be based on OS version.

Comment: Try this. Write different styles and in code behind when page is loaded, Check Os version then based on that find resource from page like Page.TryFindResource("ResouceName"). Cast it in style and assign to which ever control you want to assign.